# What do I use for "too localized" now?

Tags: discussion

I was about to vote to close as "too localized", but the changes in today's blog post just took effect. What do I do now? Here is the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307404/website-messing-up-in-ie

This is clearly too localized, isn't it? This link won't be around forever, and if I have to go to an external page for the question to make sense, what good will this do anyone in the future?

Should these types of questions still be closed (or put "on hold"), and if so, as what?

---

For now, I voted "unclear what you're asking" since I think the OP should "add additional details to highlight exactly what you need", i.e. some code. I also left this comment:

> Please post the relevant code so this will be useful in the future.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: There is no one specific mapping where all TL questions are now closed as "x".  Different types of TL questions can be closed for different reasons.  In the case of this specific question, "unclear" seems perfectly appropriate to me.  It's even better than TL.  The second offtopic sub-reason which states, "describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it" would also apply very well to this specific case.